# VBA listbox updates

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

i have below VBA code to update long list(1000) of part userform listbox with constant changes to design.
i need help with below 2 issues i am facing with code,
1)somehow, it is only updating only 1st selected item under multiselect listbox. can you pl help to check what is the issue with it to get all selected items updated by command button?
also, there are number of duplicates that i want to updates as well. however, below code updates only one and not other duplicate. can you pl help to correct code so it can update duplicates as well?

```
Private Sub cmdaction_Click()

  Dim t, t1 As String
  Dim vrech As Range, lColumn As Range
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Dim selItem As String
 
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("part bump")
  Set lColumn = sh.Range("P1:AZA1").Find(Val(txtchangenumber.Value), , xlValues, xlWhole)
  'Set lcolumn1 = sh.Range("F4:F1000")
 
  If UserForm3.txtchangedescrption.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Change Description"
    Exit Sub
    End If
If UserForm3.txtchangenumber.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Change Number"
    Exit Sub
    End If
  If UserForm3.cmbaction.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select part Action"
    Exit Sub
    End If
 
  If lColumn Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Change number not found"
    Exit Sub
  End If
 
 
  With UserForm3.lstDatabase
    For i = 0 To UserForm3.lstDatabase.ListCount - 1
      If UserForm3.lstDatabase.Selected(i) = True Then
        Set vrech = sh.Range("H4:H250").Find(.Column(7, i), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not vrech Is Nothing Then
          Select Case cmbaction.Value
            Case "RP"
              t = Chr(Asc(Mid(.List(i, 7), 2, 1)) + 1)
               t1 = Mid(.List(i, 7), 1, 2) & t & Mid(.List(i, 7), 4, 1)
              Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = t1
              MsgBox "Selected parts 'RP' Action completed"
          Case "RV"
            Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = .List(i, 7)
            MsgBox "Selected parts 'RV' Action completed"
          Case "DP"
            Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = "Deleted"
            vrech.EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
            MsgBox "Selected parts 'DP' Action completed"
        
          End Select
        End If
      End If
     
    Next i
   
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation I found that your handling of the `Selected` property is correct. I have deleted my advice in this regard and apologize for my hasty comment.

I have also re-examined your code and regret, I can't find a reason why it shouldn't deal with all selected items. without access to your workbook i don't have the ability to test and can't help you further.

Your second complaint is caused by this line of code.

```
Set vrech = sh.Range("H4:H250").Find(.Column(7, i), , xlValues, xlWhole)
```

It will find the first instance and no others. If you want the search to be repeated a loop will be required that repeats the search. Look up "VBA Find & FindNext MSDN" and you will find code samples how to construct the loop.

Note that in `Dim t, t1 As String` only t1 is a string. t is defined as a variant by virtue of not having a specified data type. This doesn't appear to be your intention.

I also noted your unusual use of `Application.Intersect`. `Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn)` should be the equivalent of the simpler `Sh.Cells(vrech.Row, lColumn)`, and it's recommended to specify the `Value` property when assigning a value to it.

Comment: Thanks for detail feedback. i am new to VBA and learning from Net and online forum. i am trying to resolve this from last couple of days. are you able to help with below code to correct it,                                                                                                                             For i = 0 To UserForm3.lstDatabase.ListCount - 1
    If UserForm3.lstDatabase.Selected(i) = True Then
        Set vrech = sh.Range("H4:H250").Find(.Column(7, i), , xlValues, xlWhole)                          thanks for your help and time.